# Google forms to calendar event issues with date format

Tags: javascript

So I have a very simple form that takes 3 inputs, a title, start and end date. I have tried to use a simple script to produce a calendar event. this can be seen below.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
    var title = e.values[1];
    var start_time = new Date(e.values[2]);
    var end_time = new Date(e.values[3]);
    CalendarApp.createEvent(title, start_time, end_time);
}
```

The issue I have is that as the date string is UK format (e.g. 05/12/2016 12:00:00) it is logging the events as 12th May as opposed to 5th December.

I am new to all of this so am looking for an elegant and simple solution I understand, not just to copy code I don't.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertUKDateToUSDate(date) {
    const arr = date.split('/');
    const temp = arr[0];
    arr[0] = arr[1];
    arr[1] = temp;
    return arr.join('/');
}
```

will convert a date string with the prefix "DD/MM/" into "MM/DD/YYYY" format. Split turns the string into an array like ["DD", "MM", "YYYY HH:MM:SS"] and then the temporary variable is used to swap the "MM" and "DD" before the array entries are joined back together with the same character that was used to split them. You'll end up with a final `onFormSubmit(e)` like this:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
    var title = e.values[1];
    var start_time = new Date(convertUKDateToUSDate(e.values[2]));
    var end_time = new Date(convertUKDateToUSDate(e.values[3]));
    CalendarApp.createEvent(title, start_time, end_time);
}
```

Obviously I'm assuming `e.values[2]` and `e.values[3]` are strings. If they're Date objects already (or if you just want a shorter solution), then consider using the [`Moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) (the premier Date object library) `format` function to convert between the formats. Normally I'd recommend using Moment anyways but you said you wanted something you could understand instead of copy.